# Saving Data in Wicket without PropertyModels

Tags: java, wicket, orientdb

I am attempting to build a web application using Wicket and OrientDB. I am trying to avoid writing/maintaining a flat Java class that represents each Class of vertex as a POJO (like an ORM). Rather, I am sending the vertices themselves all the way to the web layer. I access the properties via:

`vertex.getProperty("propertyName");`

Meaning that the properties themselves are not member variables of Vertex and thus cannot be accessed through normal getters/setters. I am running into an issue with Wicket because many components depend on a "PropertyModel" style implementation where you pass in a Model that represents one of the member variables of the class you're working with, and the data is stored in that member variable.

I have this DataView that pulls the properties of a vertex out into a Label and a TextField.

```
public VertexViewer(final PageParameters pageParameters, OrientVertex vertex)
    this.vertex = vertex;
    this.properties = this.vertex.getProperties();

    List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<>();
    keyList.addAll(this.vertex.getPropertyKeys());

    final DataView<String> propertiesView = new DataView<String>("properties", new ListDataProvider<>(keyList)) {
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(Item item) {

            String key = item.getModelObject().toString();
            item.add(new Label("property_name", key));
            item.add(new TextField<String>("edit_field", new Model<String>(properties.get(key).toString())));
        }
    };
    add(propertiesViewer);
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<wicket:extend>
    <div wicket:id="properties" style="display: table-row;">
        <div wicket:id="property_name" style="display: table-cell;"></div>
        <input wicket:id="edit_field" type="text" style="display: table-cell;"/>        
    </div>
</wicket:extend>
```

This renders exactly how I want it to, but does anyone have any recommendations on how I can save the data that is being changed in the TextFields? I can't use a model of a member variable like I would normally do on a Form because I don't ever know exactly what/how many properties are going to be in a vertex. Am I going about this in completely the wrong way? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: To put this more concisely, is there a way I can extract the new data from the Models that are created in the for() loop without adding member variables for each and every potential piece of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after much trial and error (mostly error) I found a patttern that gets around Wicket's NoSQL deficiencies and doesn't involve manually creating member variables to make Models of.

I get the `Map<String, Object>` from `vertex.getProperties()` and then create a copy of it.

```
private Map<String, Object> realProperties = baseVertex.getProperties();
private Map<String, Object> dummyProperties = new HashMap<>();
dummyProperties.putAll(realProperties);
```

This allows me to use the values in the dummyProperties as Models to store data.

```
List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<>();
keyList.addAll(getDummyProperties().keySet());

final DataView<String> propertiesView = new DataView<String>("properties", new ListDataProvider<>(keyList)) {
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(Item item) {

            String key = item.getModelObject().toString();
            item.add(new Label("property_name", key));
            item.add(new TextField<String>("edit_field", new PropertyModel<String>(getDummyProperties(), key)));
        }
};
```

From there, I put the DataView on a Form with an AjaxButton that compares the potential new values in the TextFields to the original values through some convoluted looping.

```
AjaxButton saveButton = new AjaxButton("saveButton") {
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
            super.onSubmit(target, form);
            Map<String, Object> changedProperties = new HashMap<>();
            // for each entry in the dummy values linked via PropertyModel to the TextField input
            for (Map.Entry<String,Object> dummyEntry : getDummyProperties().entrySet()) {
                // for each entry in the
                for (Map.Entry<String,Object> realEntry : baseVertex.getProperties().entrySet()) {
                    // if the keys match
                    if (dummyEntry.getKey().equals(realEntry.getKey())) {
                        // if the value has changed
                        if (!dummyEntry.getValue().equals(realEntry.getValue())){

                            // value in textField differs from value in database
                            changedProperties.put(dummyEntry.getKey(),dummyEntry.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            DBWorker worker = new DBWorker();
            // perform the update
            worker.updateVertex(recordID, changedProperties);
            // pull the fresh vertex out and pass it to the page again
            setResponsePage(new VertexViewer(new PageParameters(), new CustomVertex(worker.getVertexByID(recordID))));
       }
};
```

This ends up evaluating the new values against the old, writing the new ones back to the database, pulling back the fresh vertex and calling a new ViewerPage that accepts the updated vertex as an argument.

This works as intended, is generic to the class of vertex/number of properties, and prevents me from having to maintain ORM style Classes for each vertex class.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://github.com/OrienteerDW/wicket-orientdb.
The developer of this library also created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-5623, but this improvement didn't get much support. Please feel free to vote for it if you think it is needed.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I don't see a place where I can vote, however?

Comment: Figured it out. Registered, voted, and added to watch list. Thanks.